# How to force-close konsole?

Tags: kde, kubuntu, konsole

#### Expected behaviour

Konsole should simply close when using `Alt+F4`.

#### Actual behaviour

`Alt+F4` only closes Konsole if no command is running. e.g. this hotkey fails to close the terminal if another subshell is running in konsole.

Comment: Are you thinking about the "Confirm Close" window? What happens if you check the "Do not ask again" box and then close the window? Doesn't `Alt+F4` then simply close Konsole when used subsequently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by simply clicking on `Enable all "Do Not Ask Again" notifications" option in Konsole's settings.